# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createSecurityManager)

Tags: java, url

I want to send ping stream which is in StringBuffer sb, to server but I am getting

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission createSecurityManager)

Please help someone still struggling for day......

```
private void pushRawDataFilesToServer(StringBuffer sb) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://<ip>:8080/<appname>/WritePingData");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        try {
            BufferedWriter serverbfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
            serverbfw.write(sb.toString());
            serverbfw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this running in an applet?

Comment: show the entire exception and the line where the exception is occuring.

Comment: ya running inside                    appletjava.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createSecurityManager)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.AWTSecurityManager.checkPermission(AWTSecurityManager.java:959)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.neurosynaptic.MySecurityManager.<init>(MySecurityManager.java:5)

Comment: if i removed from applet and then create thread and what happen if i call it from applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create your own SecurityManager in an applet (in any thread).  The SecurityManager is configured by the local system as the whole point of a SecurityManager is to protect the local system (so it would be pointless to allow the applet to control its own security).

Answer (score 0):

finally My problem is solved, after calling my own function from below block of code.

```
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String run() {
                            myFunctionToPing();
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
```